# Principle axes of covariance matrix does not line up with its angle

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, covariance, eigenvector

I'm trying to get the major axis of a covariance (gradient and intercept). I'm using the sorted eigenvectors to calculate the angle of the ellipse but when I plot the resulting ellipse against the major axis, they don't line up.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

def eigsorted(cov):
    vals, vecs = np.linalg.eigh(cov)
    order = vals.argsort()[::-1]
    return vals[order], vecs[:,order]

def orientation_from_covariance(cov, sigma):
    vals, vecs = eigsorted(cov)
    theta = np.degrees(np.arctan2(*vecs[:,0][::-1]))
    w, h = 2 * sigma * np.sqrt(vals)
    return w, h, theta

def plot_ellipse(ax, mu, covariance, color, linewidth=2, alpha=0.5):
    x, y, angle = orientation_from_covariance(covariance, 2)
    e = Ellipse(mu, x, y, angle=angle)
    e.set_alpha(alpha)
    e.set_linewidth(linewidth)
    e.set_edgecolor(color)
    e.set_facecolor(color)
    e.set_fill(False)
    ax.add_artist(e)
    return e


from statsmodels.stats.moment_helpers import corr2cov
corr = np.eye(2)
corr[0, 1] = corr[1, 0] = 0.7
cov = corr2cov(corr, [1, 5])
mu = [1, 1]

vectors = eigsorted(cov)[1].T
gradients = [v[0] / v[1] for v in vectors]
intercepts = [mu[1] - (gradient*mu[0]) for gradient in gradients]

plt.scatter(*np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, cov, size=9000).T, s=1);
plot_ellipse(plt.gca(), mu, cov, 'k')
_x = np.linspace(*plt.xlim())
for i,g in zip(intercepts, gradients):
    plt.plot(_x, i + (_x * g), 'k');
```

[image: covariance]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the following line

```py
# gradients = [v[0] / v[1] for v in vectors] # wrong
gradients = [v[1] / v[0] for v in vectors] # correct
```

because the gradient is the change in `y` over the change in `x`. The figure then looks like this.
[image: Ellipse Plot]

I also added `plt.figure()` before the plotting begins and `plt.axis("equal")` after the `plot_ellipse` call.

I would also like to cite the [numpy.linalg.eigh](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html) documentation:

> w : (…, M) ndarray
>
> The eigenvalues in ascending order, each repeated according to its multiplicity.

and thus the `eigsorted` function could be left out.

Comment: Can you explain why this fails if I don't set the aspect `equal`? What if I want an unequal ratio? Surely the lines derived from the same matrix as the ellipse should line up with the ellipse in any aspect ratio?

Comment: If the axis are not equal you are plotting a different ellipse. Imagine for example a circle which is a circle for equal axes but in fact an ellipse if one of the two axes is lengthened. For this circle the lines could be the lines `y = x` and `y = -x` (arbitrary). Now if the aspect ratio is changed, the correct lines would be `x = 0` and `y = 0` so I actually think that the aspect ratio has an influence here. Also would you mind accepting  the answer as it solves the bug?

Comment: Hang on. Given that I'm plotting lines that are derived from the same covariance matrix as the points, they should always line up. In whatever aspect ratio I choose! Forget the Ellipse, the line should always line up with the direction of the points

Comment: I am not quite sure about your argument. Scaling the plot is equivalent to multiplying each point by a diagonal matrix `D` and the scaled covariance will thus be `D C D` (where `C` is the old covariance matrix). In contrast the slopes of the lines will only be scaled by `D`. I think it would be best to try and calculate a simple example on paper. If you can prove that the eigenvectors of `D C D` are the eigenvectors of `C` just scaled by `D` you would have really shown your claim.